# preferred way of accessing child class members from base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

What is the best way to access child class properties in the base class. It seems that if  I am using inheritance I need to solely depend on methods instead of properties [because separate set of properties exists for separate classes]. Is there any recommended,safe way of accessing child class properties from base class. or is this any preferred way of refactoring the code, so that I can access child class members via a base class. i know the use of virtual functions but I don't know how to use it to set values for the child class members variables.

```
class Abc
{
  public int Abc_1 {get;set;}
  private int _abc;

  virtual int DoCalculationonAbc(int a)
  {
    return abc_1 * a;
  }

  virtual void SetValueToPrivate(int a)
  {
    _abc = a;
  }
}

class Def:Abc
{
  private int _def;
  private int _def2;
  public int Def_2{get;set;} // what is the preferred way to set values this property

  override public void SetValueToPrivate(int a)
  {
     _def = a;
     //_def2 = ??
  }
}

Main()
{
  Abc ab = new Def();
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd give a concrete example.

Comment: The reason you have to depend on methods is because your base class never knows what properties a child class has. And your base class does not know where it has been inherited. If the property is already declared in the base class, you cannot still access the child class copy because you do not know if your child class has overridden it or not.

Comment: In your example, it depends on what you want to do with _def2, since this is newly declared in the Def class. Your property accessor Def_2 is the preferred way of setting the values to _def2;

Comment: @ryadavilli but Def_2 is not accessible using an Abc instance.

Comment: Exactly. Def_2 is defined in Def Class.... Abc does not know anything about the existence of a Def class or a Def_2 property. Why would you expect it to be accessible? Can you expand your code sample to add into Abc, how you expect to use Def class members in there?

Comment: what if Def_2 is relevant to Def class only. Other inheriting classes doesn't need Def_2 propery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20795/discussion-between-logeeks-and-ryadavilli)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to do something like this, you should know ahead of time which properties you want available to your super class. You would declare them as protected in your base class so that your subclasses can set them according to their own rules.

You cannot, as previously said, access a child's newly-declared property (like `_def2` and `_def` in class `Def`) from the base class.

If you instantiate a child type and assign it to a super type, like `Abc ab = new Def()`, you are deciding to treat `ab` as an `Abc`, meaning, you are letting go of `Def`'s specific members and functions when you do stuff to `ab`. It is true that `ab` is truly a `Def`, BUT you must manipulate it as an `Abc`.

Similarly, if you pass a `Def` in a function `someFunction(Abc ab)`, that function better treat `ab` as an `Abc`. `someFunction(Abc ab)` is created to process whatever child types of `Abc` could be, but only by their common properties and methods as defined in `Abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Members of a child class can not be accessed from a base class since it does not know which class has inherited it. The only way to reach to child class members would be achieved by polymorphism and by downcasting.

```
    class Base{
        public Base();
        int a;
    }

    class Derived : Base{
        public Derived();
        public int b;
    }
    Base testBase = new Test;
    Base testDerived = new Derived;
    testBase.a = (Derived)testDerived.b; // Downcasting here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var testDerived = (Derived)new Derived(); //casting to derived class required to access its members.

testBase.a = testDerived.b;
```